# Authentication for Shopify + Rails + Angular App using Auth0 - Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, shopify, omniauth, auth0

I have this very confusing error and I have no idea how to search for it. I am using auth0 on an angular + rails app to help with authentication between a Shopify App in Rails and the front end of the app in Angular, I am using webpacker.

The Rails app currently works with Shopify but we are currently working a separate interface on the front end in angular in. When I remove AuthService from the providers array in app module everything works fine. But when AuthService is available in providers array, I am getting this error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?)

My AuthService is exactly same as what I found in the documentation and git commit.

Here's what my AuthService parameters look like:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:5000/callback',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
```

Currently, when I authenticate with Rails, Everything works fine. But once we work the redirect to angular app. The session is lost.
How can we get the session parameters/request parameters from rails in my angular 4 app.